# Selecting only a portion of a shapefile by location - ArcMap

Tags: gis, arcgis, shapefile, esri, arcmap

I have two layers: One of the Mississippi River Basin and one of the counties within the 48 states. 
[USA counties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seRdF.png)

[Misissippi River Basin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcgfO.png)

I'm having no trouble selecting the counties within the Basin, but I also need to select the portions of the counties only partially within the basin. I know how to select the entirety of the counties that are partially within, but I want to select only the portions that are within the basin shapefile so I can calculate the percentage of those counties that are within the MRB.

Thanks, let me know if you need anything else

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, SE also has a [GIS site](https://gis.stackexchange.com/) that might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading your question correctly, the end result you want is the proportion of each county that is in the basin?

I would use the Union function to combine the two layers. The output is essentially sub-counties polygons. 
You then calculate the area of those shapes that are both county and basin, but selecting by attribute.

Then use Dissolve on the counties using a sum rule on your area field (so that all the pieces are added up if there are unexpected splits).

Then calculate the total area of the counties in a new field and use the two new fields to calculate the proportion.

I hope this helps